# How to make and use GIMP templates?

Tags: gimp, template-design

I want to use a template (with layers, fonts, guides, etc) and pull it out from a folder to make repetitive images in GIMP, like I can in Inkscape.

How is this possible?

Comment: Hello, celiapgt, can you tell us something about your efforts? Have you seen the documentation related to the [templates](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-template-dialog.html) (also [here](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-file-save-as-template.html))?

Comment: Hi, Paolo Gibellini. I'm sorry. I didn't read the rules before writing this question.
Yes, I'd tried to use current documentation, as Andrew Robinson suggested down there, but cannot use guides, objects, etc... I was wondering if someone knew a workaround for this, some new plugin or something. GIMP lacks this great feature, I believe.

Comment: I agree. At the moment the templates are a little poor. As Andrew Robinson says in his answer, you can bypass this limitation by saving your templates in xcf format.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure (based on the documentation) templates are just Height, width and color space. I guess if you want to make a template like the following:[image: Resume emplate]

You could save it and open it later as an xcf. This also means you need a template in xcf format. That's all I can say.